# Is there a way to press - "dash" on logitech GHub Lua?

Tags: lua, macros, logitech-gaming-software

As the title says i am trying to press the "dash" button on my keyboard, however i'm not sure what to use since every name that i have tried comes back with an error or a different key gets pressed; here is what i tried:

- "-": Error
- "dash": Error
- "minus": "'" gets pressed
- "mdash": Error
- "ndash": Error

And unfortunately i haven't been able to find any documentation regarding the names, only for the methods: https://douile.com/logitech-toggle-keys/APIDocs.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 equivalent ways to simulate pressing minus key:

```
PressAndReleaseKey("minus")  -- symbolic name
PressAndReleaseKey(0x00C)    -- scancode
PressAndReleaseHidKey(0x2D)  -- HID code
```

Comment: Yea, i tried "minus" and it still put ' instead of the dash, so i installed the united states layout and it worked fine